# Render a custom directive when loaded dynamically from controller

Tags: angularjs

I have three custom directive, say `<sample-grid></sample-grid>` , `<sample-form></sample-form>` and `<sample-view></sample-view>`. These are defined in the following way:

```
angular.module("MyApp").directive('sampleGrid', [ function() {
    return {
        scope : {},
        restrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl : 'view/templates/sample-grid.tmpl.html',
        controller : 'SampleGridCtrl',
        scope: {
              scnid: '=',
          }
    };
} ]);
```

I have a main view where I am using `<md-tabs>` from `angular material` in following way -

```
<md-tabs>
    <md-tab ng-repeat="tab in myCtrl.pageTabs track by $index">
        <md-tab-label>{{tab.tabName}}</md-tab-label>
            <md-tab-body>
                <div id="tab.tabName" ng-bind-html="tab.tabHTML"></div>
            </md-tab-body>
    </md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

also the controller for this view defined as

```
angular.module("MyApp").controller("myCtrl",['$log','$scope','$sce', '$compile', function myCtrl ($log,$scope,$sce,$compile) {
    var homeScope = this;
    homeScope.pageTabs = [];

    var newTab = {};
    newTab.tabName = "Sample";
    newTab.tabHTML = $sce.trustAsHtml("<sample-grid></sample-grid>");
    newTab.tabAction = "grid";
    homeScope.pageTabs.push(newTab);

    var template = angular.element(document.querySelector('#Sample'));
    $compile(template)(homeScope);
```

}])

The requirement is: user will be able to add new tabs in view, and I have to show one of the three custom directives in the view based on the selection. So I have to just push new tab objects into `homeScope.pageTabs` with the required property.

The problem is : After pushing the tab object, new tab is created but the custom directive  does not render into view. I can see it in the console like :

```
<div id="tab.tabName" ng-bind-html="tab.tabHTML">
    <sample-grid></sample-grid>
</div>
```

I have seen answers here such that I have to use `$compile` to render it correctly. I tried that, But I could not get the proper solution.

So my question is how I can achieve this functionality? And, is there any other easy and possible way to achieve this?

Comment: found my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38224198/angular-directive-doesnt-render-the-template-after-adding-html-dynamically-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed your controller logic a little bit. You have to use `compile` a little bit different.

```
angular.module("MyApp").controller("myCtrl",['$log','$scope','$sce', '$compile', function myCtrl ($log,$scope,$sce,$compile) {
    var homeScope = this;
    homeScope.pageTabs = [];

    var template = $sce.trustAsHtml("<sample-grid></sample-grid>");
    var linkFn = $compile(template);
    var content = linkFn(scope);

    var newTab = {};
    newTab.tabName = "Sample";
    newTab.tabHTML = content;
    newTab.tabAction = "grid";
    homeScope.pageTabs.push(newTab);
}])
```

Comment: `var content = linkFn(scope);'  is the scope refer to homeScope here? or $scope?

Comment: it should be $scope

Comment: Thanks buddy. This helps a lot. @benjamin. Also the link I shared above works, but needs an extra directive though $sce and $compile not needed.